# Group top n and botton n in one row SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report

I have a daily report that shows me a simple grid: [Id], [Descripction] and [Qty].
User ask me to show only the top 10 Qty Values, good, I apply the filter Top n, **but** ask too to show the other values in one row that say "Others", I know how to do this in a graph, but I never do that in Tablix.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: do you mean that you show 10 rows (the top ten) and then 1 total row that adds up all the other quantitys not in the top ten based on id, desc?

Comment: Yes, that exactly, I must to have 11 rows, the top ten row by row and the No top ten sum in one row.

Answer (score 0):

Create some test data:

```
DECLARE @TopTen TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    Description VARCHAR(100),
    Qty INT
)

INSERT INTO @TopTen
( Id, Description, Qty )
VALUES
( 1, 'Test1', 1 ),
( 2, 'Test1', 1 ),
( 3, 'Test1', 1 ),
( 4, 'Test1', 10 ),
( 5, 'Test1', 10 ),
( 6, 'Test1', 10 ),
( 7, 'Test1', 100 ),
( 8, 'Test1', 100 ),
( 9, 'Test1', 100 ),
( 10, 'Test1', 1000 ),
( 11, 'Test1', 1000 ),
( 12, 'Test2', 1 ),
( 13, 'Test2', 1 ),
( 14, 'Test2', 1 ),
( 15, 'Test2', 10 ),
( 16, 'Test2', 10 ),
( 17, 'Test2', 10 ),
( 18, 'Test2', 100 ),
( 19, 'Test2', 100 ),
( 20, 'Test2', 100 ),
( 21, 'Test2', 1000 ),
( 22, 'Test2', 1000 );
```

Here I take the data and sort out the quantities into a CTE

```
WITH T AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY QTY DESC) RN
    FROM @TopTen
)
```

Now lets pull the top ten records from the CTE and then union and sum up all the other records giving some bogus id's to show which are totals records

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT t.Id, t.Description, t.Qty, t.RN 
FROM T WHERE t.RN <= 10
UNION
SELECT 9999 AS Id,
    MAX(t.Description) AS Description,
    SUM(QTY),
    9999 AS RN
FROM T 
WHERE t.RN > 10
GROUP BY t.Description
) d
ORDER BY RN, Description
```

Here is the output:

```
Id  Description Qty RN
10  Test1   1000    1
11  Test1   1000    2
21  Test2   1000    3
22  Test2   1000    4
18  Test2   100 5
19  Test2   100 6
20  Test2   100 7
7   Test1   100 8
8   Test1   100 9
9   Test1   100 10
9999    Test1   33  9999
9999    Test2   33  9999
```